# Mysterious Permission Problems Windows 7 - Access denied no luck with takeown

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-permissions

I have no idea how this has happened.  I am running a VM on a drive and out of nowhere all permissions on that drive seem to have somehow become corrupt.

I cannot open directories on the drive.  Everything results in Access Denied.

I have tried running icacls and takeown.  Both result in access denied.  Any suggestions, I have used Windows for years and have never seen anything like this.

I appreciate your help in advance.

**Edit:**

I disabled UAC and can now access the drive - ODD.  What would UAC have to do with this?

Comment: UAC has everything to do with it. Bypassing it removes all sanity checking on the ACLs, so you are free to mess with it as you like.